# Error when using Active Record method 'where' to merged results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I have Active Record result:

```
a = User.all.where(name: "John")
b = USer.all.where(name: "Sara")
```

Then is merged these two arrays into one:

```
c = a | b  # or c = a + b
```

The problem is that I can't do:

```
d = c.where(age: 17)
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #Array:0x0000556a5456c3e0

I want to find something from a merged record results...Thank you!

Comment: you can't query on array set

Comment: AFAIK `User.all.where(name: "John" || "Sara")` should be same as `User.all.where(name: "John")`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh you're right

Comment: What's wrong with `User.where(name: ["John", "Sara"])`?

Comment: @Phlip yeah it works and maybe I'll need it somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions), you can now use `.or` to query on more than one conditions. You can do:

```
users = User.where(name: 'John').or(User.where(name: 'Sara'))

# Add more conditions to above result
users.where(age: 17)
```